# Does a power supply GND connection need a resistor?

Tags: power-supply, resistors, ground, safety

I am creating a power supply for my work station, and I have a input of 13.5 - 19V DC from a converter on `POWER_JACK`.

From this input voltage I want to derive 12V, 9V, 5V, and 3.3V, and each has a corresponding output connector. `USB1` and `USB2` are also output connectors to charge USB devices.

`LED_ON` is for an LED that simply indicates that the device is powered.

`FAN` is to power a 5V fan should it be necessary to keep the device cool.

I want to have a ground terminal, and I was wondering, do I need a resistor before the ground output? Also, is the remainder of my circuit safe?

Here is the schematic:
[image: Power Supply Schematic]

Comment: What causes you to think that you need a resistor "before" the ground output?

Comment: No, and those diodes will result in a nominal voltage drop up to ~0.7v on each output, so your 5v might drop down to 4.3v, your 3.3 to 2.6, etc.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks You, I there any way to escape the voltage drop, or could i just get rid of the diodes without repercussions?

Comment: What about using buck converters instead? Regarding your circuit, the datasheet recommends some capacitors, also you have to calculate how much heat is being dissipated by each regulator at your maximum load and design an appropriate heatsink.

Comment: The diodes do nothing for you because they are in the power supply. So they will not prevent an accidental polarity reversal that occurs in the connection to a device.

Comment: A diode between the power supply's real ground and the ground that is offered by the power supply to devices is a very silly thing. The power supply should expose the real galvanic ground.

Comment: Thank You!
@Kaz Thanks, I will get rid of the diodes, since they offer no extra safety. :)

Comment: What is the current requirement for each rail.?

Comment: Generally in EMI/EMC labs for ESD testing, people use 1M resistor for strapping. For controlled suppression of ESD pulses. I am not sure if you any specific requiremnts on this. select proper package for LM117N if your current is more. It looks thermal resistance of one of the package is about 136 °C/W.

Comment: Ok, I am connecting a 13.5v power source to POWER_JACK, the FAN is for a 5v fan I own if the power supply ends up getting hot(I will probably not need this, and if I do use it I will add another switch for the fan), USB1 and USB2 will be connected to usb outputs so I can charge devices such as phones, and I will connect a led to LED ON, as an indicator light.

Answer (score -6):

If Your components are supposed to get 12V and you are saying that your input is of 13.5 - 19v then you should use a resistor on the ground or on the positive connection.